# Perl Magick Resize Color Issue

Tags: perl, imagemagick

I'm writing a script to resize gif images. I've notice that the images I create have a smaller image size, but take up more room on disk. I think I've tracked down the cause of the problem. The original images when examined in photoshop only have 4 colors in their color table (white, gray, grayer, black) while the new images have 256 colors in their color table. I can't find a way to copy the color table from the incoming image, is there some way to control this? Here's my script

```
use Image::Magick;
my $image = Image::Magick->new;
$image -> Read( 'test.gif' );
$image -> Resize(geometry=>"50%");
$image->Write( 'test-out.gif' );
```

Any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Sample() instead of Resize() to keep the same number of colours

```
$image->Sample(geometry=>"50%");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the number of output colors using the `-colors` option. It's a good idea to include the `+dither` option, even if you're sure you have the same number of colors in both input and output. In straight ImageMagick, it would look like this:

```
convert test.gif +dither -colors 4 test-out.gif
```

I don't know the syntax for the perlMagick API, but this should get you pretty close.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've used the solution above which works perfectly.